# using math symbol \times in symbolic x coords

Tags: pgfplots

I need to use the math symbol \times on the x axis because the x axis represents image dimensions. But latex doesnt allow me to proceed with this. It gives me hundreds

> missing \endgroup inserted

error messages.

Could someone please help me

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-.1in}{+.0in} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
scaled y ticks=real:150,
ytick scale label code/.code={},
ymax = 150, ymin = 0,
symbolic x coords={8 \times 8, 16 \times 16,32 \times 32,64 \times 64},
xtick=data,
height=11cm,
width=8cm,
grid=major,
xlabel={Bitmap Dimensions},
ylabel={Accuracy},
legend style={
cells={anchor=east},
legend pos=south east,
},
cycle list name=black white
]

\addplot coordinates {
 (8 \times 8, 22)  (16 \times 16, 23)  (32 \times 32, 23)  (64 \times 64, 122) };

 \addplot coordinates {
 (8 \times 8, 56)  (16 \times 16, 55)  (32 \times 32, 99)  (64 \times 64, 140) };

 \addplot coordinates {
 (8 \times 8, 22)  (16 \times 16, 75)  (32 \times 32, 89)  (64 \times 64, 130) };

 \addplot coordinates {
 (8 \times 8, 108)  (16 \times 16, 145)  (32 \times 32, 144)  (64 \times 64, 149) };

 \addplot coordinates {
 (8 \times 8, 109)  (16 \times 16, 111)  (32 \times 32, 145)  (64 \times 64, 145) };

 \addplot coordinates {
 (8 \times 8, 56)  (16 \times 16, 111)  (32 \times 32, 150)  (64 \times 64, 146) };

 \addplot coordinates {
 (8 \times 8, 77)  (16 \times 16, 111)  (32 \times 32,  133)  (64 \times 64, 147) };
\legend{$A$,$B$,$C$,$D$,$E$,$F$,$G$} 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{
Accuracy variation with increasing bitmap dimensions} 
\label{fig:accresplot} 
   \end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please post a MWE, so we don't have to guess which packages you are loading. It's not clear to me what you really want to do: What do you mean by a coordinate (8x8,77)? Since all the data in the example are "square", I'm guessing you want coordinates (8,77) instead and then somehow show that the numbers on the x-axis represent image dimensions.

Comment: Are you using the `scaled y ticks=real:150` code to divide your y coordinates by 150? In that case, I would recommend using `y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1/150}}`, which transforms the data, not just the tick labels, which will lead to better tick label values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't use symbolic coordinates for this, as it makes the data input incredibly tedious. Instead, I would recommend just setting the tick labels to the desired format, and using "proper" coordinates for the data.

Instead of providing the data inline in each `\addplot` command, I would use a table. Also, you can simplify your code by using `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` to loop over the data series.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
8   22  56  108 109 56  77
16  23  44  145 111 111 111
32  23  99  144 145 150 133
64  122 140 149 145 146 147
}\datatable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ymin = 0, ymax=1,
y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1/150}},
xtick=data,
height=11cm,
width=8cm,
grid=major,
xlabel={Bitmap Dimensions},
ylabel={Accuracy},
legend style={
    cells={anchor=east},
    legend pos=south east,
},
cycle list name=black white,
xticklabels={$8 \times 8$,
    $16 \times 16$,
    $32 \times 32$,
    $64 \times 64$
}
]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {1,...,6}{
    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=#1] {\datatable};
}
\legend{$A$,$B$,$C$,$D$,$E$,$F$,$G$} 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

`\times` breaks inside `\csname` that `pgfplots` needs to build an inverse lookup table.

Many TeX compilers (pdfTeX, LuaTeX, XeTeX) provide `\ifincsname` that can be used
to redefine `\times` that it survives a `\csname`.

```
\let\OrgTimes\times
\protected\def\times{%
  \ifincsname
    \string\times%
  \else
    \OrgTimes
  \fi
}
```

Then the symbolic coordinates can be given as

```
$8 \times 8$, $16 \times 16$, ...
```

(Math mode is needed because of `\times` and the spacing around `\times`.)

Inside `pgfplots.code.tex` it could be fixed by redefining
`/pgfplots/symbolic coords/.code 2 args={...}`. There are three constructs (`\csname` and `\pgfutil@ifundefined`) with

```
pgfp@symb@coords@#1@...
```

that can be replaced by

```
pgf@symb@coords@#1@\detokenize\expandafter{...}
```

But I stop here, because Jake has already provided a much more elegant version
for generating the diagram without needing symbol coordinates.